# Failed to connect port 443: Timed out

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1, php-5.4

I have magento on server , I'm trying to access its of REST api in my local. But I find an error "Failed to connect  port 443: Timed out". 
here is my code

```
        $userData = array("username" => "admin", "password" => "admin123");

        $ch = curl_init();
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "https://mymagentocom/rest/V1/integration/admin/token");
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "POST");
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, json_encode($userData));
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array("Content-Type: application/json", "Content-Lenght: " . strlen(json_encode($userData))));
        curl_exec($ch);
```

Comment: do you managed to solve this problem?